# Guzzle output same response data when call API url

Tags: php, codeigniter, guzzle

I'm using codeigniter with guzzle to hit a API url, this is what I need happen:

I send a Post request to the URL, example: https://api.domain.com/redirectUrl
passing some headers too, after that, the response is a url like this: http://my.url/auth/redirects/RHGEWQQWJQJ8VWG4YJGG4GYYMR36AH5F2W3644DNHWA675JQ7Q
this URL has a token, and when you go to this URL, the user can access the application, but this token is valid to only one session, if I close the tab or window, I need generate this URL again with a new hash, my problem is, the guzzle is generating the same hash again and again. and I'm stuck here trying figure out why.

this is my code: https://gist.github.com/leandroruel/e9f4f312bad50b7c6443c6680c0e53e7

Comment: from where this random string comes - show the exact function. Does turning off cache in response header help something?

Comment: this string, is a url, and this is a response when i do a request to the API

Comment: try to return random string from api, to check if url changes evey time, if not- it might be the cache issue